# Trouble understanding how to use build.hxml

Tags: build, sublimetext3, haxe, haxeflixel

I'm building a game using the HaxeFlixel framework. I'm using Sublime Text as my IED. I'm also following [this](http://haxeflixel.com/documentation/hello-world-command-line/) as my first program so I have run `flixel tpl -n "HelloWorld"` to setup my project.

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

My `build.hxml` looks like this:

```
#-main source/MenuState
#-neko bin/text.n 
#lime test neko
-main Main.hx 
-neko Test.n  
#-cmd neko Test.n
```

My research has included:

[Youtube video starting at 7:22](https://youtu.be/0a2FIEi5UnU?t=7m22s)

[Andy Li’s Blog](http://blog.onthewings.net/2013/03/04/hxml-tricks-every-haxe-user-should-know/)

If someone could show me what I'm doing wrong and explain the solution I would be so happy as this has taken a few hours of my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're applying the wrong solution to the problem :)

`build.hxml` is essentially a file with multiple arguments that haxe should note while compiling. When compiling haxe, you could run `haxe -x SomeHaxeFile.hx`. However - this is the solution for compiling *raw* haxe. Different haxe library's ask to be compiled in their own ways, as, if they are complex enough (ie - haxeflixel), there are lots of things running in the background of compilation, for example putting assets like images into the build.

Haxeflixels build method is through `lime`s build system. So, to run on neko, you would type into terminal `lime test neko`. This is the best way to compile haxeflixel games, and is shown in the official haxeflixel guide. http://haxeflixel.com/documentation/hello-world-command-line/

This command should be ran in the folder with `project.xml`, as that file contains the information haxeflixel (and thus haxe) needs to build. You can ignore hxml files while working with haxeflixel.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of the `build.hxml` file to run those commands for you? I've run my program using `lime test neko` I was just looking for a way to not have to continue type the command every time I make a change to a file.

Comment: Not quite. Hxml files stipulate arguments to a haxe compile, where all of the work is done by haxe. You are doing a lime build, which does more than just compile with arguments. Hxml files _can_ run command line commands, through `-cmd *command*`, however using a hxml file just to run a terminal command is silly. For that, you're better off making a batch file (or similar) with `lime test Neko` in it, because you can double click the file to execute it. Also, to use a hxml file, you must still type `haxe build.hxml`, every time you make a change.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your response,